# ERROR Unity with native android java : java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no type "" found and so no field "currentActivity"

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am making an app that needs to communicate with an android aar.
It used to work well a few weeks ago. Since then I've been working on the Unity UI and didn't test the android communication in awhile.

Now I'm getting an error that I simply don't understand:

```
2023/08/12 02:04:24.141 3621 3686 Error Unity AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no type "" found and so no field "currentActivity" could be found in class "Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;" or its superclasses
2023/08/12 02:04:24.141 3621 3686 Error Unity java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no type "" found and so no field "currentActivity" could be found in class "Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;" or its superclasses
2023/08/12 02:04:24.141 3621 3686 Error Unity     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
2023/08/12 02:04:24.141 3621 3686 Error Unity     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.-$$Nest$mnativeRender(Unknown Source:0)
2023/08/12 02:04:24.141 3621 3686 Error Unity     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$C$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source:122)
2023/08/12 02:04:24.141 3621 3686 Error Unity     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
2023/08/12 02:04:24.141 3621 3686 Error Unity     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
2023/08/12 02:04:24.141 3621 3686 Error Unity     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$C.run(Unknown Source:24)
2023/08/12 02:04:24.141 3621 3686 Error Unity   at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () [0x0008d] in /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/AndroidJNI/AndroidJNISafe.cs:24
2023/08/12 02:04:24.141 3621 3686 Error Unity   at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.GetStaticFieldID (System.IntPtr clazz, System.String name, System.String sig) [0x0000e] in /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/An
```

It happens anytime I try to do anything related to Unity/Android.
Even when I call functions on Permissions.
For example

```cs
AndroidJavaClass unityPlayerClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
```

or

```cs
Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH)
```

causes this error to popup

This is my manifest file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector"
                  android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is my publishing settings and Android build options:
[image]

I'm at a complete loss because I haven't changed anything related the Unity/Android stuff and it used to work fine (I double checked git for any revisions on the manifest file and nothing changed).

Any help would be super appriciated.

Comment: did you added any new Unity Android plugin?

Answer (score 0):

This was an absolute nigthmare to debug. Absolutely nothing to go on. But I finally figured it out.

DO NOT assign a field that derives from a java class in it's definition within a monobehviour. This did not give me any log, warning or error to indicate I shouldn't do this.
Don't do this:

```cs
private AndroidThermalPrinter.UnityAndroidGetConnectionStatusCallback m_UnityAndroidGetConnectionStatusCallback = new AndroidThermalPrinter.UnityAndroidGetConnectionStatusCallback();
```

Do this instead:

```
private AndroidThermalPrinter.UnityAndroidGetConnectionStatusCallback m_UnityAndroidGetConnectionStatusCallback;

public void Initialize(){
m_UnityAndroidGetConnectionStatusCallback = new AndroidThermalPrinter.UnityAndroidGetConnectionStatusCallback();
}
```

To figure that out I first made a new scene with a simple toast that executed in awake.

Then I added that code to my original scene. And I started removing stuff from my scene until that toast didn't throw the error anymore.

That narrowed it down to the monobehaviours that had those declarations.

I hope that this will help whoever gets that error in the future to avoid wasting an entire weekend trying to figure it out...